# iPhone Web App -- Links launched via "Home Screen" mode

Tags: iphone, web-applications, homescreen

I have an mobile web application that I'd like users to be able to use on "home screen mode" (that is, adding it as a bookmark to the homescreen, and then launching the web app via the home screen button).

However, this seems to behave differently than if it the web application was accessed via mobile Safari. For example, whenever I click a link on the web application (even an internal link), it separately launches an instance of Safari instead of displaying the page within the current "browser" (or whatever is launched when you click a bookmark on the home screen). How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window)