# iPhone Web App on Home Screen + Facebook Authenticate

Tags: ios, facebook, cakephp, authentication, homescreen

Gurus of SO

I have a working web app which works well enough with Facebook Connect. But when I post the Web App to the Home Screen on iOS 4.3.4 & click on 'FB Login' in the app -> it triggers Safari to open up and I end up leaving the Home Screen view.

Is there anyway to login from the Home Screen app itself and not trigger Safari?

Thank you.

Comment: this may help you : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried target="_webapp", target="_blank", etc none of those worked for me.

This bit of javascript worked just fine for me:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('<put your facebook login URL here>','_parent'); ...
```

Comment: Doing this means I can't use the javascript API directly? I have to parse the return url for information? Any example of tying this into the FB javascript API?

Comment: i don't know how or why this works but I am SO happy it does. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

It is doing this to verify the Facebook login session. Currently, you cannot avoid this since your web app must go to Facebook dialog anyway to have the user login if they haven't already.

Comment: I figured it out, it is possible by a tiny JS trick to open links in the same window.

Comment: Oh, I see. I understood your question as asking if it was possible to avoid the redirect in the first place. If doing it on the same window works, then I think you're fine. Glad you got the workaround. Perhaps you can post your workaround here so other folks can benefit.

Comment: iUsable: I'm interested to know what the "tiny JS trick" was? Thanks in advance!