# Home screen app (android) facebook login opens browser

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, mobile, homescreen

I'm working on a website that is focused on mobile users and uses a manifest to be opened standalone when added to the home screen. This works well, except for the Facebook login function. Whenever I try to login it opens the Facebook link in the browser outside the app. I then have to manually return to the app and reload the page to be logged on.

How can I stay inside the standalone app when logging in?

I tried using `window.location` as explained in [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2899099) but no change. I also tried using `window.open` as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590504) but again, no luck.

You can try it on this [test page](http://few9.com/stackoverflow/fbtest) that has an adjusted manifest and login option to stay inside the test page. I used a Samsung Galaxy S5 for testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not stay inside your app while logging.

Redirecting the user to the Identity provider (Facebook) in your case it is the normal life-cycle of an Oauth2 login or Single Sign On login. On the OAuth2 server you can set the **redirect url** which is the address you want the user to be send after login.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#redirecturl

Login to your facebook app account: https://developers.facebook.com/apps and change the **redirect url** from your app control panel.

Comment: The flow works, i am redirected to my own page. But i'm no longer in my standalone homescreen app, but in the regular browser.

Comment: Alright, I guess it's just something for my phone then. Thanks for the effort and testing!

Comment: @HugoDelsing Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the exact problem.

Comment: It's phone specific diego. The `window.location` works on all phones I tried accept my galaxy s5.