# What controls whether an iOS web app launched from a Web Clip opens links in mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari

What controls whether an iOS web app launched from a Web Clip opens links in mobile Safari? (As opposed to the special browser just for the web app.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the comments to [iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window)

Thanks to Oskar Austegard

> To state the obvious and make this explicit: iOS treats links in Web
>   Apps as something that should be opened in Safari, and javascript
>   location changes as an in-app action that is allowed to saty in the
>   web-app. The code above works because it prevents the default link
>   behavior, replacing it with a js nav call. – Oskar Austegard Sep 15 at
>   13:11

Comment: Also stated in some official Safari documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/mobile/userExperience/_index.html