# Keep web app in standalone mode on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone-standalone-web-app

After searching Stackoverflow and Google, I have not found a working solution.

I need a web app to remain in standalone mode when changing pages (clicking links). Currently, when any links are clicked while in standalone mode, they are launched in a new window in Safari, and exits standalone mode.

How can I prevent links from opening a new window so that it remains in standalone mode.

This piece of code is tested and does not work:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

It seems as though this is being circumvented by Safari while in standalone mode, preventing this from working. Is there a new work-around?

This app is being presented tomorrow, so PhoneGap is not an option; are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `return false;` in your click closure.

Check out this post, [iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window)

Comment: The `e.prevenDefault()` has the same purpose as the `return false` while being much more explicit.