# iPhone WebApp opens links in safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, web-applications

When I add my 'web app' to my home screen on my iPhone, then open it and click a link, it opens Safari.

I've found a couple of solutions to my question but they don't seem to work:

[iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window)

```
$('a').live('click', function (event)
{      
var href = $(this).attr("href");

if (href.indexOf(location.hostname) > -1)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = href;
}
});
```

http://jakeboyles.com/2011/01/16/how-to-build-an-iphone-and-ipad-web-app/

```
<a ontouchstart="window.location=yourlink.html' ">Your Link</a>
```

Both of these posts/tutorials were written before iOS5. Is there a new method? Am I doing something wrong?

Appreciate your help

Comment: What's your question? You've only stated what happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to make your home screen app an iframe, and making all anchors target it. No javascript needed.

Alternatively:

```
$('a').on('click touchend', function(ev){

    $(this).preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');

});
```

Never use "touchstart" for something like links. You only want to detect when the user stops touching the link. Same thing for detecting key presses, mouse clicks, etc. Its the *end* of the event you want to detect.

.live has been deprecated in the latest versions of jQuery, so use .on() from now on and it wraps seamlessly around extant and non-extant elements.

Answer (score 1):

This javascript code works for iOS 5 (it worked  for me):

In the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenLink(theLink){
    window.location.href = theLink.href;
}
</script>
```

In the link that you want to be opened in the same window:

```
<a href="(your website here)" onclick="OpenLink(this); return false"> Link </a>
```

The code is based on this comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-web-app-meta-tags/comment-page-1/#comment-10699

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine on the iPhone 5

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Stop the default behavior of the browser, which
    // is to change the URL of the page.
    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // Manually change the location of the page to stay in
        // "Standalone" mode and change the URL at the same time.   
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
 });
```

Remember to link to the newest version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Im the one that wrote the article you are referring to. I still use my javascript method and it works fine for me. The touchstart works fine for web apps as it takes a little longer for the browser to render it. If you are planning on makign a native app then don't use it, but I have used touchstart for many apps and it works fine.

Thanks
Jake Boyles