# Jquery Mobile MVC3 iPad Web App Linking

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ipad, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

With JQuery Mobile and MVC3 ASP.NET, on an iPad, created a home screen bookmark.
The app pulls up with no problems, it does not show safari's bar. 
I login to my app and click a link, ***THE LINK OPENS SAFARI, NOT INTENDED***.

My question is how to prevent the clicked link from opening outside of my bookmarked app?
I've tried:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function () {
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

The code above seems like it should work based on the docs from jquery mobile.
When I click the link/button the link/button highlights but no error or page load.

Also, another question is why when I leave the app and come back the session dies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS will treat links where you have stipulated data-ajax="false" as a link that should be opened by Safari. I had the same problem in my MVC site that is using jQueryMobile. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window) very helpful and the following piece of code works very well in my application.

```
$("a[data-ajax='false']").live("click", function (event) {
    if (this.href) {
        event.preventDefault();
        location.href = this.href;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this webpage you are linking to being packaged with the app? You need to do so. The app cannot find it and goes out to the browser.

The code itself is fine. 
http://jsfiddle.net/m35BU/5/

Session variables are stored on a server...are you talking about a javascript cookie?

If so, unless you set an expiration date for the cookie (mktime()+3600*7  for 7 days) or whatever, it will expire when the app is closed.

Comment: Thanks, I know sessions are stored on the server. Never the less a cookie is stored on the client for asp.net. I'm pretty sure all pages are internal and packaged.

Comment: If the links have rel="external" in them, it might open a browser.

Comment: They don't! I'm going completely by the book. If I get a working example up, I'll post it to git.

Comment: If android, post an .apk or dropbox it for me.

Comment: My issue is not with Android, although, I have not tested Android.