# iOS new windows open in appmode

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I have a very strange error. I have an webpage that runs in Appmode (when you add to homescreen on iOS). I have one A element that transfer to another page in the same domain (test2.html). If I click on it, the appmode is quited and a new browser window opens.

However if I make a location.href = 'test2.html' it works. And now the strange part, on test2.html I just have one A element with href="test1.html", and now it works.

I have a thesis that every link will work in your own domain if you sometime have done a location.href before clicking any other link.

My test case:

**Test2.html**

```
        <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="transfer();">Test1</a>
        <script>
        function transfer(){
            location.href = "test1.html";
        }
        </script>
```

**Test1.html**

```
        <a href="test2.html">Test2</a>
```

You can change Test2 so it similar to Test1 and just change the href and it will broke.

I really have no ide why this is happening. Why does it work just after you have done a location.href in the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem. For now, I solved it simply by making my link return false:

```
<a href='#' onclick='doSomething(); return false;'>test</a>
```

EDIT: This seems like a better answer: [iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window)