# Apple meta tags & startup images not working

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, media-queries

I have a Rails app which is using a responsive Boostrap layout to scale down for mobile.
I want to get a splash screen and hide the task bar on iphones

I have the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "KegTracker" %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <!-- iPhone -->
    <link href="/assets/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png"
          media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPhone (Retina) -->
    <link href="/assets/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png"
          media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPhone 5 -->
    <link href="/assets/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1096.png"
          media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '144x144' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '114x114' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '72x72' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png' %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico', :rel => 'shortcut icon' %>


    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCDh4VYHZ56mUlwkE6gE16cDRxCaCLjJQE&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://jawj.github.com/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js">
    </script>

  </head>
```

All the images are linked correctly. The touch icons work fine, but the touch-startup-image and apple-mobile-web-app-capable tags don't seem to work at all on either Safari or Chrome on my iPhone 4S running 6.1

Has anyone got any ideas? Is Bootstrap overriding the tags?

Comment: This looks to be a well maintained gist on the issue, https://gist.github.com/tfausak/2222823 . Remember that this will only work once you've added the app to the home screen and opened it from there (sorry, I just wanted to cover all the bases).

Answer (score 0):

As Justinavery said, you have to add to the homescreen for this to work and then click on the icon.

Also, to make all links work inside the 'headless view' that this generates you need to add this piece of JS to your code.

```
<!-- to stop the links loading in another window -->
<script>(function(a,b,c){if(c in b&&b[c]){var d,e=a.location,f=/^(a|html)$/i;a.addEventListener("click",function(a){d=a.target;while(!f.test(d.nodeName))d=d.parentNode;"href"in d&&(d.href.indexOf("http")||~d.href.indexOf(e.host))&&(a.preventDefault(),e.href=d.href)},!1)}})(document,window.navigator,"standalone")</script>
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8173161/678849)