# Rails 3.1 Ajax: Why doesn't my link_to's with :remote => true generate a JS request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm implementing Ajax into my existing Rails 3.1 app. I'm comparing with [Samnang Chhun's excellent tutorial](http://wowkhmer.com/2011/09/19/unobtrusive-ajax-with-rails-31/) - his works, mine doesn't.

This is my link_to:

```
<%= link_to('Do some Ajax!', @activity, :remote => true) %>
```

This my controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js

  # ...

  def show
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @activity
  end

  # ...

end
```

My `views/activities` folder contains both a `show.html.erb` and a `show.js.erb`.

**UPDATE:** This is my included JavaScript files:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/activities.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/add2home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.dropdownPlain.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I click it, the page refreshes, a straight HTML request, which is also verified by the server output (see line 2):

```
Started GET "/activities/18-leka-titta-pa-mig" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-13 20:58:43 +0100
  Processing by ActivitiesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"18-leka-titta-pa-mig"}
  Activity Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "18-leka-titta-pa-mig"]]
WEBSITE: Babycenter.com
  Tag Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = 18 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Activity'
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered activities/show.html.erb within layouts/application (63.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_facebook_sdk.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered activities/_filter_tabs.html.erb (3.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 107ms (Views: 79.8ms | ActiveRecord: 21.6ms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have any javascript included in <head>?

Comment: Yes, see updated post above.

Comment: @TomSöderlund, did any of the answers given solve your problem?

Comment: @zeantsoi no, not yet.

Comment: Now found it, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by coincidence. I turned out I used an old JavaScript snippet to disable iOS Safari to open links in new windows. This script wasn't compatible with the Rails 3 way of doing Ajax.

By replacing the script with the latest from [iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window) I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the jquery UJS hooks - https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: actually these hooks are included in the head. What might be missing is `jquery-rails` gem.

Comment: `gem 'jquery-rails'` is in my Gemfile.

Comment: One message: `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.` The source of the message is `oauth:1`.

Comment: I think the above message is from the Facebook SDK though.