# How should I organise my jquery code to make it dry?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling on how to organise my jquery code.

I have the following functions:

```
function Function1() {
  $('a').not('a.dialog').click(function(event){
    // Do something.
  });
};

function Function2() {
  $('a.dialog').click(function () {
    // Do something.
  });
};
```

Function1 is called on every page, function2 is called only on a single page.

What is the best way to remove the duplication between these two functions specifically the reference to 'a.dialog'.

Should I be using global variables? or is the above code the best I can hope for?

------------------ UPDATE ------------------

The specifics of the two functions are as follows:

Function1 does this: [iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window)

Function2 opens a dialog lightbox.

Comment: I think it really comes down to what the function does...A simple if check inside can work on both.

Comment: you can move your function to a separate js.

Comment: Why not using a single script file containing both functions and which would be included in both pages ?
Btw, considering how http requests and connexions are slow, parsing the same small function twice is probably more efficient.

Comment: `$('a').click(function(){if($(this).hasClass('dialog')) { DO SOMETHING..}...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to do it like that :

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert('work');
})

$('.dialog').unbind().click(function(){
    alert('really work')
})
```

Reduce the number of if...

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SJvrD/

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements." - just FYI. I imagine they will eventually be deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Function1() {
  $('a').click(function(event){
     if($(this).is('.dialog')) //or .hasClass('dialog')
         //...
     else //...
  });
};
```

Comment: This would work, however I would prefer to keep the separation between the two functions. Also this solution would introduce an "if" overhead for most of the pages on the site.

Comment: in the if part (for dialog) you could call a external function setted inside the specific page

Comment: If you want separation than why do you think you need to combine them in the first place!

Comment: @epascarello - to avoid duplication, as more likely to introduce bugs. Also to avoid the repeat search overhead.

Comment: Don't worry about `if` overhead, you can execute it tens or hundreds of millions of times before reaching the perceivable 100ms lag threshold...