# Turning a Web App into a Semi-Native App using Apple meta tags

Tags: html, ios, safari, meta-tags

I included the following to my `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icons/appicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/loading.png">
```

My goal here is to give the user:

> the ability to turn a site into what's looks like a native app, which
>   launches without any browser chrome. [[link]](http://spinejs.com/mobile/docs/header)

So, using Safari or whatever browser on iOS, when the user clicks on `Add to Home Screen` while opening *my web app* home page, an icon gets added to the Home Screen. When you click on it, a semi-native app gets launched perfectly.

**The Problem?** From the semi-native app, if I navigate to another page (i.e. click on any link which redirect to another page in the same site), this link gets loaded on the browser (a separate Safari session opens) and not in the same semi-native app.

So,

- Is this normal? Does this *conversion to semi-native app* supports one-page sites only?
- If it is not normal, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS treats links in Web Apps as something that should be opened in Safari. For more information on how to solve this: [iPhone Safari Web App opens links in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898740/iphone-safari-web-app-opens-links-in-new-window)